# Why do ONLY Indian staffing/"consulting" bodyshops flood the US job market?

Tags: financial-markets

Why do **ONLY** **Indian** staffing/"consulting" bodyshop agencies flood the US job market, and why do they flood **ONLY** the US?

This is definitely not just "Well, many Indians have at least somewhat understandable English."

Why do Russian or Chinese bodyshops not flood the US? There are tons of English speakers there.

There are tons of quite competent German and French speakers in Russia and Eastern Europe, but they do not make unsolicited calls to job seekers in Germany and France, to tell them about "an urgent position with their client."

Why do **Indian** bodyshops not flood the UK, Germany, France, the Scandinavian countries?

What is so unique in this combination of the US job market and **India** that makes this phenomenon persist?

Comment: And second: Can you please back up your claims with some statistics? I doubt their veracity.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-are-there-so-many-Indian-recruiters-consultancies-in-the-US-Over-the-few-months-that-I-have-been-looking-for-work-I-would-say-only-one-or-two-were-not-Indians-from-India

Comment: That is not a statistic, that is some internet person's opinion. If this is the standard of proof, I can both prove and disprove the existence of aliens.

Comment: @denesp Worse, it is someone's impression, a classic case for the law of small numbers: universal claims based on too little data, like just our personal experience, which we unjustifiably tend to think that it is "representative of the population".

Comment: Down vote due to lack of solid statistic. Perception is just selective bias, not fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do Indian bodyshops not flood the UK, Germany, France, the
>   Scandinavian countries?
>
> What is so unique in this combination of the US job market and India
>   that makes this phenomenon persist?

You touch on a worsening problem that apparently very few people have noticed, and which merits scrutiny. The least harmful effect intermediaries --from India and elsewhere-- cause is the *false and misleading impression* that jobs (as reflected in labor statistics) are being "created". Indian intermediaries abound in Canada as well, and they are not unheard of in Europe. But whether or not these agencies originate from India is irrelevant to the actual waste of time (and energy) their fake "screening processes" cause to candidates.

The problem is not just the mere flooding of so-called "consulting" agencies, but also --and more important-- that they usually post job advertisements that don't exist. That is why these agencies hardly ever provide any specifics about the alleged project or job position for which they approach the candidate.

> There are tons of quite competent German and French speakers in Russia
>   and Eastern Europe, but they do not make unsolicited calls to job
>   seekers in Germany and France, to tell them about "an urgent position
>   with their client."

Non-Indian intermediaries and fake ads about "an urgent position" are rampant also in Europe. For instance, it is common for "positions" allegedly located in continental Europe to be advertised and screened by agencies located in the UK. In and of itself, that combination is not an unequivocal indicative of being a fake ad. However, the idea that employers in continental Europe would skip the multitude of nearby intermediaries and approach an unknown "recruiter" from far away is bizarre.

My experience with intermediaries from Europe is that they often try to gather information from the candidate as to where else he has recently applied, what those other projects/positions consist of, and so forth. That is the intermediaries' attempt to figure out what customer(s) to approach and offer staffing services.

**Edited to add ...**

One possible reason behind the combination you mention (US job market and Indian agencies) might be an intent to abuse the U.S. visa & immigration system. For years I have been hearing about Indian recruiters (for instance, [Infosys](https://www.firstpost.com/business/high-stakes-for-infosys-as-visa-fraud-case-trial-begins-next-week-417132.html)) being investigated/charged for visa fraud.

To sponsor a foreigner for a work visa and/or an employment-based [U.S.] green card, the sponsoring agency/employer needs to prove to the Department of Labor that there are no qualified candidates in the U.S. market to fill a position.

By posting advertisements and/or conducting unsolicited interviews such as the one you found on Quora, the Indian agency might be trying to fabricate evidence that its efforts to find qualified, [U.S.] domestic candidates were fruitless. But this is just my conjecture as I revisit your inquiry. Only an investigator or an honest insider could speak with certainty about this issue.

Comment: At least in the US technology market, non-local/foreign bodyshopping is overwhelmingly dominated by Indians - recruiters & devs. It's easy to prove it by looking at screen shots of the average job hunting email box of IT US devs, or walk into the IT dept of the average US corporation. From personal experience, US devs are never contacted by Russians, Ukrainians, Chinese recruiters, although there are plenty of able English speakers in Russia, Ukraine, China. Have these people just not "discovered" the US yet, or maybe the actual revenue of such "consulting" industry doesn't justify their time?

Comment: IMH understanding, many of these Indian agencies do not publish fake positions as their mainline strategy, that might be quite a waste of even their (less valuable) time. But they do have close to zero reputation, they create a lot of noise for both candidates and employers. They either overwhelm the employers with tons of (often irrelevant) resumes, or they are ignored by employers due to their huge number & nonexistent reputation. In that sense yes, they do create an enormous amount of wheel spinning (I suspect more for the candidates, as employers could've made them disappear quite rapidly)

Comment: @rapt Of course. And the interview experience you found on Quora is quite representative of many "job" interviews I have entertained [in the U.S.] from Indian recruiters. But the points I made in my answer are to clarify that (1) Indian intermediaries also flood the Canadian (not just the U.S.) job market, and (2) also French/German/English intermediaries flood European labor markets. I just edited my answer to add a *plausible* (meaning that I cannot assert with absolute certainty) explanation for the particular context about which you inquire.